# Make numpy.sum() return a sum of matrices instead of a single number

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, sum

I am doing a fairly complicated summation using a matrix with numpy. 
The shape of the matrix is `matrix.shape = (500, 500)` and the shape of the array is `arr.shape = (25,)`. The operation is as follows:

```
totalsum = np.sum([i * matrix for i in arr])
```

Here is what I don't understand:

`np.sum()` is very slow and returns a single float, `float64`. Doing the same operation with Python's `sum.()`, i.e.

```
totalsum2 = sum([i*matrix for i in arr])
```

Preserves the shape of the matrix. That is, the resulting shape is `totalsum2.shape() = (500, 500)`. Huh?

I also think it is strange that `np.sum()` takes longer than `sum()`, particularly when we are working with numpy ndarrays.

What exactly is going on here? 
How is `np.sum()` summing the above values in comparison to `sum()`?

I would like `np.sum()` to preserve the matrix shape. How can I set the dimensions such that `np.sum()` preserves the matrix size and does not return a single float?

Comment: This operation should simply be written as `np.sum(arr) * matrix`.

Comment: @Ophion the array and matrix are not the same shape. I want to multiply the entire matrix by each value in the array. Then, I want to sum all the resulting matrices.

Comment: This can be written in einsum notation as `np.einsum("k,ij->ij", arr, matrix)`. As can be seen there are no common indices between tensors. You can verify this yourself by computing any of the above methods and the answer you selected as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must call np.sum with the optional axis parameter set to 0 (summation over the axis 0, i.e the one created by your list comprehension)

```
totalsum = np.sum([i * matrix for i in arr], 0)
```

Alternatively, you can omit the brackets so np.sum evaluate a generator.

```
totalsum = np.sum(i * matrix for i in arr)
```

Comment: Letting the axis parameter = 0, is rather "sumatting over the axis 0" rather than "no summation" over the axis. It works because the list comprehension used effectivelly creates a 3 dimensional data structure, which first (0th) axis as taken by Numpy is the dimension created by "stacking" all copies of the multiplied `matrix`.

Comment: Note that "Alternative": giving a generator to numpy.sum is now [deprecated](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/release.html).

Answer (score 5):

Python's regular sum() task is taking every item in that list and adding them together. When arrays of the same size are added together, you just add them elementwise. For example:

```
test1 = np.array([[4,3],[2,1]])
test2 = np.array([[8,9],[1,1]])
print test1 + test2
```

Returns

```
[[12,12]
[3,2]]
```

Whereas with np.sum, you are adding along an axis or axes. If you want to maintain things being in an array, and you want to use np.sum, you will want to project your operation (multiply by i in array) into a third dimension, and then use np.sum(axis=2).

This can be done using:

```
np.sum(matrix[:,:,np.newaxis] * array[np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:],axis=2)
```

Comment: It just works by passing "axis=0"  on the O.P. 's call: his comprehension creates a three dimensional data structure fro  which the first axis is the desired one.

Comment: Tom: @jsbueno is correct. Passing "axis=0" gives totalsum.shape  = (500, 500). Passing "axis=2" gives totalsum.shape = (24, 500).

Comment: Yes, axis=0 is what you want to use if you do things via Yoann's method. And, based on a few quick tests I did, that's the method you want to use if you're computation time limited. For the example that I showed, however, you need to use axis=2. Alternatively, you can rearrange the np.newaxis positions to make axis=0 the one you want to sum over.

Comment: @jsbueno `np.sum([i * matrix for i in arr])` first creates a 3D contagious array then sums all elements. `sum([i*matrix for i in arr])` creates a list of 2D array's then adds them together using `np.add.reduce`. The difference is subtle, but very important. This answer can be rewritten as `np.sum(arr[:, None, None]) * matrix, axis=0)` which may make things more analogous.

Comment: @Ophion: thanks for clarifying. My original (first) comment was made when this answer was in a provisional stage, and Tom had actually mistakenly described the situation when "axis=0". It has been fixed shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

```
[i*matrix for i in arr]  # list of matrices
```

The list above is a list of matrices so when you use sum, it will add the arrays.

```
In [6]: matrix = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

In [7]: matrix
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])


In [9]: [i * matrix for i in (2,4,8)]
Out[9]: 
[array([[2, 4],
        [6, 8]]), array([[ 4,  8],
        [12, 16]]), array([[ 8, 16],
        [24, 32]])]
```

Please check the help for np.sum

```
    File:        /home/ale/.virtualenvs/ml/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyaxis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False) Docstring: Sum of array elements over a given axis.

Parameters
---------- a : array_like
    Elements to sum. axis : None or int or tuple of ints, optional
    Axis or axes along which a sum is performed.
    The default (`axis` = `None`) is perform a sum over all
    the dimensions of the input array. `axis` may be negative, in
    which case it counts from the last to the first axis.

    .. versionadded:: 1.7.0
```

It says that if you don't define an axis it will sum over all the dimensions. Example:

```
In [4]: np.sum(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]))  # 1 + 2 + 3 + 4...
Out[4]: 10
```

Why is np.sum taking longer? well intuition says that in the expression `[i*matrix for i in arr]` you are creating a new array for each `i` which then np.sum will sum over all arrays.

There might be other reason, but I'm guessing it's that.

Comment: I tried to fix matrix/matrices, but you also made edits, so I hopefully now have set the answer back to your last edit.

Comment: @Ale Numpy will first build all the `i*matrix` arrays then when `np.sum` is called build a 3D array from the list of arrays. The overhead is all of the extra in-memory copying.